# Validar o formulário sem enviá-lo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Eu estou tentando validar um formulário para verificar se tudo está ao menos preenchido.
O problema é que eu não estou submetendo o formulário, pois não posso recarregar a página. Estou apenas capturando o evento por JavaScript e realizando a função.

Segue o código abaixo:

```js
$('#nitrogenio').click(function (e) {
if($("#commentForm").validate(){
var combo=$('#haoum3').val();
var area=$('#area4').val();
var resultado;
if ( combo=="ha" ) {
        resultado = 10*Number(area);
        $("#divPrincipal4").html('<p class="alert-success">Irá precisar de '+ (Number(resultado)-Number(10)) +'-'+ resultado + ' Kg de Nitrogênio </p>');
     }
     else
     {
        resultado = 10*(area/Number(10000));
        $("#divPrincipal4").html('<p class="alert-success">Irá precisar de '+ (Number(resultado)-Number(10)) +'-'+ resultado + ' Kg de Nitrogênio </p>');
     }
 }

  });
```

Para fazer a validação e impedir que faça a função caso esteja vazio eu coloquei um

```js
if($("#commentForm").validate()
```

A ideia até funcionou, mas o problema é que quando está tudo correto com o formulário, ele realiza o envio da página e recarrega. Alguém tem alguma idéia do que seja?

Comment: Que elemento HTML é o `#nitrogenio`? `<button>`? `<input>`?

Comment: O que você quer dizer com "recarrega" ?

Answer (score 1):

se é que eu entendi o que você precisa, um desses exemplos abaixo vai servir:

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Validando formulários e previnindo o envio se não for aprovado na validação</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
{
 $("#commentForm").submit(function()
 {
  var combo=$('#haoum3').val(),
  area=$('#area4').val(),
  resultado;
  if(combo == "ha")
  {
   resultado = 10*Number(area);
   $("#divPrincipal4").html('<p class="alert-success">Irá precisar de '+ (Number(resultado)-Number(10)) +'-'+ resultado + ' Kg de Nitrogênio </p>');
   alert("o form vai ser enviado");
   return true; // NÃO PREVINE o envio do formulário
  }
  else
  {
   resultado = 10*(area/Number(10000));
   $("#divPrincipal4").html('<p class="alert-success">Irá precisar de '+ (Number(resultado)-Number(10)) +'-'+ resultado + ' Kg de Nitrogênio </p>');
   alert("o form não vai ser enviado");
   return false; // PREVINE o envio do formulário
  }
 });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="divPrincipal4"></div>
 <form id="commentForm" action="valida.php" method="POST">
  <select onchange="if($(this).val() == 'ha'){$('#area4').val(0.4);}else{if($(this).val() == 'cl'){$('#area4').val(0.8);}else{$('#area4').val(0.1);}}" id="haoum3">
   <option>Selecione</option>
   <option>ha</option>
   <option>cl</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" name="area4" id="area4" />
  <input type="submit" id="nitrogenio" value="Validação" />
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

ou:

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Validando formulários e previnindo o envio sempre</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
{
 $("#commentForm").submit(function()
 {
  var combo=$('#haoum3').val(),
  area=$('#area4').val(),
  resultado;
  if(combo=="ha")
  {
   resultado = 10*Number(area);
   $("#divPrincipal4").html('<p class="alert-success">Irá precisar de '+ (Number(resultado)-Number(10)) +'-'+ resultado + ' Kg de Nitrogênio </p>');
  }
  else
  {
   resultado = 10*(area/Number(10000));
   $("#divPrincipal4").html('<p class="alert-success">Irá precisar de '+ (Number(resultado)-Number(10)) +'-'+ resultado + ' Kg de Nitrogênio </p>');
  }
  alert("o form não vai ser enviado");
  return false; // PREVINE o envio do formulário
 });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="divPrincipal4"></div>
 <form id="commentForm" action="valida.php" method="POST">
  <select onchange="if($(this).val() == 'ha'){$('#area4').val(0.4);}else{if($(this).val() == 'cl'){$('#area4').val(0.8);}else{$('#area4').val(0.1);}}" id="haoum3">
   <option>Selecione</option>
   <option>ha</option>
   <option>cl</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" name="area4" id="area4" />
  <input type="submit" id="nitrogenio" value="Validação" />
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode colocar a função de validação no atributo `onsubmit` do formulário.

```
<form ... onsubmit="return validarFormulario();">
</form>
```

```
function validarFormulario() {
    var possuiErro = false;
    // condicoes

    return possuiErro;
}
```

Com isso, se a sua função de validação retornar `true` o formulário é enviado e se retornar `false` o navegador interrompe o envio do formulário.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#nitrogenio').click(function (e) {
    if($("#commentForm").validate() {
        var combo = $('#haoum3').val();
        var area = $('#area4').val();
        var resultado;
        if (combo == "ha") {
            resultado = 10 * Number(area);
        }
        else
        {
            resultado = 10 * (area / Number(10000));
        }
        $("#divPrincipal4").html('<p class="alert-success">Irá precisar de ' + (Number(resultado) - Number(10)) + '-' + resultado + ' Kg de Nitrogênio </p>');
    }
    e.preventDefault(); // Assim evita o comportamento padrão do browser de recarregar a página.
});
```